# How to save data from an array object to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've been having a problem with saving data from an array object to the MongoDB database. I have my schema for the main document with embedded subdocuments. The saves for the main document and all the other subdocuments were successful except for a subdocument which is an array.

As you can see from the screenshot, the fields from the subdocuments are not being saved to the database.

[Screencap from Robo 3T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX5qY.png)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Sample request object:

```
{
  "incidentNumber": "IN1001",
  "status": "New"
  "Approval": {
    "approvers": [
      {
        "approverType": "Asset Management",
        "approverName": "Bob",
        "approvalDate": 1234
      },
      {
        "approverType": "HR",
        "approverName": "Janet",
        "approvalDate": 1234
      },
      {
        "approverType": "Finance",
        "approverName": "Bill",
        "approvalDate": 1234
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const approvalSchema = new Schema(
  {
    approvers: [
      {
        approverType: {
          type: String
        },
        approverName: {
          type: String
        },
        approvalDate: {
          type: Date
        }
      }
    ]
  }
);

const headerSchema = new Schema(
  {
    incidentNumber: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      enum: ['Completed', 'Draft', 'New', 'Pending', 'Submitted']
    },
    approval: [approvalSchema]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Server code:

```
let incidentNumber: "IN1001";
let status: "New";

app.post('/create-incident', (req, res) => {
  const header = new Header({
    incidentNumber: incidentNumber,
    status: status,
    approval: [
      {
        approvers: [
          {
            approverType: req.body.Approval.approvers.approverType,
            approverName: req.body.Approval.approvers.approverName,
            approvalDate: req.body.Approval.approvers.approvalDate
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  });
});

header
  .save()
  .then(Header => {
    res.status(200).send(Header);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
```

Comment: Just assign `approval: req.body.Approval`. It's an "array", so everything after that point needs an "index" to access the elements in the object. Without that the result is `null`, but you want to add the whole array anyway, so just do that.

Comment: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Your code seems fine to me as I ran it, the only problem that might be in your req body. Your `req.body.Approval.approvers.approverType` body may be returning `undefined`

Comment: @NeilLunn I followed your advice by just putting req.body.Approval, and it magically worked! Actually, the first time I did that, it didn't work (maybe because of the nested square brackets and curly braces, I don't know), so what I did was instead of mapping field by field, I just mapped by subdocument all throughout. It really reduced my verbose code to just a few lines. Thanks for this wonderful tip! Thanks also, Sachin, for taking time to look into my problem. You guys are amazing.